# Ue5 AI MoveTo does not work

Tags: ai, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

I have been having problems working with AI MoveTo and created a very basic version in the hopes of finding the problem:

[image: Blueprint simplified]

[image: Simple character with the default skeleton mesh]

As you may see, I have one single character with the default skeletal mesh and one call to AI MoveTo at the beginning of the game to move to a hardcoded location. This call resolves with on fail callback.

I have versions with navmeshbounds volume & random navigatiable points & different characters etc.. but they also fail and figured this simplified version better underlines what the problem may be.

This aside, is there a way to look at details on why on fail is triggered ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not change anything in particular, after a full restart next day, all the AIMove To blueprints started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I see you were using a custom scene (Not the template ones). Keep in mind that when using AI navigation functions, you **must** have a *navMeshBoundaryVolume* in your scene where your desired AI Actor/Pawn would be contained inside that volume.